# Problems using SoapUI: "A required header representing a Message Addressing Property is not present

Tags: web-services, soapui

While trying to tets my application i uses wsdl page to create new SoapUi project, but invoking of any method returns following error message.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Solved. Need to disable WS-A option in SoapUi settings.